# How can ClickOnce change the app.config from development to deployment one?

Tags: clickonce

I have a development app.config and a deployment app.config. I need clickonce to change it on deployment.Is this posible to be done automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way would be to copy the app.config file in the pre-build script that you can define in the app's property page *Build events*.

You could do either:

1) Create a solution config used only for deploying to production, and switch on that in the script, e.g.

```
if  ($(ConfigurationName)) == (PublishConfig) call ReplaceAppConfig.cmd
```

or, if you only build the publish config on a specific machine:

2) Always run the script in the pre-build event:

```
call CheckAndReplaceAppConfig.cmd
```

and the CheckAndReplaceAppConfig.cmd would in this case have:

```
IF (%MACHINENAME%)==(PUBLISH_SERVER) ReplaceAppConfig.cmd
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to re-build your application, you can try this approach that works on the deployed files directly.

As part of our testing workflow, we often setup multiple deployments of the same application with only differences in the `.config` file. We really don't want to have to re-publish every time we want to add a new deployment with a different config file. Since ClickOnce demands that everything will be signed and hashed, it's not possible to just change the `myapp.exe.config.deploy` file contents and expect everything to work. So what you can do is use `mage.exe` to update your manifests after you make the change.

As mentioned [here](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/xaml/a8788ed5-c1b5-41d5-b49c-ea4760c3b820/update-configuration-of-a-clickonce-wpf-application-using-mage-or-mageui.aspx), what you basically need to do is:

First, go to the "Application Files\MyApp_1_2_3_4\" directory in your deployment dir

You have to rename all the files from `something.extension.deploy` to `something.extension`

Then Run:

```
mage -Update "Application Files\MyApp_1_2_3_4\myapp.exe.manifest"
mage -Sign "Application Files\MyApp_1_2_3_4\myapp.exe.manifest" -CertHash my_ceritficate_thumbnail
```

Then rename the files back to their original names (add the `.deploy` extension)

Finally, run:

```
mage -Update MyApp.xbap -appmanifest "Application Files\MyApp_1_2_3_4\myapp.exe.manifest"
mage -Sign MyApp.xbap -CertHash my_certificate_thumbnail
```

Alternatively, to avoid renaming the files you can tell Visual Studio to not add the `.deploy` extension when publishing (go to Publish...Options in the visual studio project) and next time, when you publish, the files won't get that extension. My only guess at the danger of that is hitting firewall problems with certain users when they try to download `.exe` or `.dll` files.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the VS tools, then the config files are all part of the signed portion of the deployment. As such, the best way to do this is via your *build* tools - i.e. build a different version with dev/live/etc config files.

With 3.5SP1 you can [opt out of the signing](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/05/12/visual-studio-2008-and-net-framework-3-5-service-pack-1-beta.aspx); I don't know if you can do this via the IDE - presumably you can do it if you do it manually (via mage), but this is a lot more work...

Comment: It can be done with Mage, but we generally opt for different build versions. As Marc says, it's simpler.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a better way of doing it:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsto/archive/2010/03/09/tricks-with-app-config-and-clickonce-deployment-saurabh-bhatia.aspx

Comment: This link is dead. It would have been helpful if you had pasted some of the salient content.